# Configure default domain in Putty

Tags: ssh, putty

I work at a big company with its own domain, and I SSH into servers every day, many times a day. Is it possible to simply type `hostname` instead of `hostname.my.domain.com` and still SSH successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure a search domain for DNS. (Not specifically for puTTY, but for all programs doing a DNS lookup).

How you do that depends on your OS.

## For most unix like environments:

Open `/etc/resolv.conf` and a a `search mydomain.tld`.
You can add multiple search domains.

## For windows

- For windows: Go to control panel,
- Network and sharing center,
- select your LAN connection, then [Properties]
- Select TCP/IP v4, then [properties
- Go to [advanced]
- tab "DNS". Add the search domain.

[image]

## For any OS configured to use  DHCP

Any big company should be using a DHCP server. That can supply not just IP leases, but also DNS server names and *which paths to search*. This assumes you have control over these. If not, ask IT to add your own domain.

---

Whenever you now try to resolve a hostname the resolver will not only try to resolve the hostname, but also hostname.my.omain.tld.  This will work for anything which uses DNS (e.g. puTTY, Firefox, ...)

Hopefully needless to say, but replace 'my.domain.tld' with your actual domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an entry to your `hosts` file should be sufficient. You'll need to know the IP address of the remote server -- you can find that out by running a `ping` on the full hostname.

1. Log into your Windows computer as an administrator.
2. Open up Notepad with administrative privileges. On Vista and later, it should be sufficient to click Start, type `notepad`, and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter, or right-click the Notepad icon and select Run as administrator.
3. With your administrator Notepad, find the file `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.
4. To the end of this file, add a line with an entry like the following: `208.88.72.142 hostname` where the IP and hostname are replaced with those of the server you want to connect to.
5. Save and close. It should work immediately.

You can also set your DNS search path to include `my.domain.com` (which your IT administrator should arguably have done) -- bring up the properties for your network adapter by whatever means are appropriate for your version of Windows, then bring up the properties for the "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" entry, then Advanced, then on the DNS tab enter "my.domain.com" under "Append these DNS suffixes".

Comment: What if company changes its IP frequently... There's a reason why company didn't share IP directly.

Comment: Then that's what the second half of the answer is for (as unlikely as it is that the poster's company is changing the IPs of servers at all frequently...)